# Running select query on db for different variables using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using python to establish db connection and reading csv file. For each line in csv i want to run a PostgreSQL query and get value corresponding to each line read.

DB connection and file reading is working fine. Also if i run query for hardcoded value then it works fine. But if i try to run query for each row in csv file using python variable then i am not getting correct value.

```
cursor.execute("select team from users.teamdetails where p_id = '123abc'")
```

Above query works fine.
but when i try it for multiple values fetched from csv file then i am not getting correct value.

```
cursor.execute("select team from users.teamdetails where p_id = queryPID")
```

Complete code for Reference:

```
import psycopg2
import csv


conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='', user='', password='', host='', port='')
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open('playerid.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        queryPID = line[0]
        cursor.execute("select team from users.teamdetails where p_id = queryPID")
        team = cursor.fetchone()
        print (team[0])

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT concatenate the csv data. Use a parameterised query.
Use `%s` inside your string, then pass the additional variable:

```py
cursor.execute('select team from users.teamdetails where p_id = %s', (queryPID,))
```

Concatenation of text leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection.
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Comment: was getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Figured it out from the document in this case it should be like ...execute('...p_id = %s', (queryPID,))